# How to delete one side bones

Tags: rigging, add-on

With the [Blenrig addon](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/56965fc3c379cf44546120e1)

I dont want to keep the mirror or symmetry option both side. I delete the half side (hand) but it deleted the other side also. Is there any option to control just to delete the half part and keep the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Tool panel (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>) > *Options*, you must have enabled the *X-Axis Mirror* option, disable it.

[image]